# Fetch the current location of the user

Tags: android

What changes do I need to make in my code to make it fetch the current location of the user rather than predefined latitudes and longitudes?

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.safwan.mypersonal;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                                             .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng cannaughtplace = new LatLng(28.6315,77.2167);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(cannaughtplace)
            .title("Marker in Cannught place"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(cannaughtplace));
    }
}
```

Comment: The first change you need to make is to format the code you posted here. Nobody likes to read this.

Answer (score 0):

```
  locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    try {
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
    if(location==null) {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }

    if (location != null) {
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double longg = location.getLongitude();
        mMap.moveCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat,longg) , 14.0f) );
        startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class));
        ismarkervisible = true;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Device Failed To Fetch Lat Long", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: try something like above